# FPDF: Resize image keeping aspect ratio

Tags: php, fpdf

How can I make an image smaller or bigger keeping aspect ratio?

`$pdf->Image($Imagen,10,25);`

Comment: Use the PHP [gd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) functions to create an image the correct size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scale = 1.25;    
$pdf->Image($Imagen,$originalWidth * $scale, $originalHeight * $scale);
```

So you're looking to scale the image, just apply a scale multiplier. > 1 will enlarge the image while < 1 will shrink the image.

Comment: this seems to work. But if the image scale is too large it does not work as expected. I have a image of 1200x675 px and when I try to scale it to 0.30 it does not work as expected. To get the dimensions I use `list($originalWidth, $originalHeight) = getimagesize($Imagen);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the original aspect ratio first. w/h.
Then you either have a target width or height you want to achieve. targetX.

```
newHeight = ( width / targetWidth ) * height

newRatio = newHeight / oldHeight
```

or

```
newWidth = ( targetHeight / height ) * width

newRatio = newWidth / oldHeight
```

Then

`$pdf->Image($Imagen, curWidth * newRatio, curHeight * newRatio);`